# Elegant way to mask-merge two strings in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, merge

For example if we have two strings `"abc"` and `"1234"` i want result `"abc4"` (the first string masks second). (If we draw them vertical it's like a wave comes from left and tuch chars)

```
             "a"  "1"            "a"
 wave ->     "b"  "2"   result   "b" 
             "c"  "3"            "c"
                  "4"            "4"
```

I start with this solution with Haskell

```
slice from to xs = take (to - from + 1) (drop from xs)
merge l1 l2 = if length l2 > length l1 
                then l1 ++ slice (length l1) (length l2) l2 
                else l1
```

Can you please provide some more elegant\compact solutions.

Answer (score 7):

You just need a special merge function

```
> let merge [] ys = ys
|     merge xs [] = xs
|     merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : merge xs ys
```

or using `drop`

```
> let merge2 x y = x ++ drop (length x) y
```

Answer (score 5):

You want kind of a "`zipLongest`", and [*`transpose`*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) is kind of like that:

```
maskMerge1 :: [b] -> [b] -> [b]
maskMerge1 as bs  =  map head $ transpose [as,bs]
              -- or:
              --        head <$> transpose [as,bs]
```

This is pretty compact and elegant (with big thanks to [@leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) for the comments!).

Looking from above,

```
    [ "abc" ,        [ ['a' ,'b' ,'c'     ] ,
      "1234" ]         ['1' ,'2' ,'3' ,'4'] ]
    ----------      --------------------------
                     [  "a1","b2","c3","4"  ]   -- transpose
    ----------      --------------------------
      "abc4"         [  'a' ,'b' ,'c' ,'4'  ]   -- map head
```

The code with `length` in the other answer also works, and even for an infinite `x` despite calling the dreaded `length` on it, but it will retain the whole of `x` in memory because of calling the `length` on it.

Comment: This is actually one of the few instances where I'd prefer `head` over `take`. Since `transpose` never generates empty column-lists, `head <$> transpose [as,bs]` should be safe. I don't like `>>=` here, because it obscures the fact that the positions are preserved. (If for some reason there _should_ appear empty columns, then `head` will fail in a more obvious, debuggable way.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout interesting and valid observations, thanks. using `take 1` instead of `head` has become a second nature for me by now, but of course `head` being safe here is the whole point of this code. :) re `>>=`, it was a shortening of `concatMap` since the OP asks for a "compact" code; and `concatMap` was itself a shortening of `map (take 1) >>> concat`; keeping the `map` would indeed make it self-evident that there are no empty lists inside and `concat` is a counterpart to the initial `[ , ]`.

Comment: ooops, the `concat` was because of `take 1`. how embarrassing. :)